# When i scroll down, element appends to parent element. But, when scroll up, how can I turn back original status?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm testing a sticky navigation by using jQuery. Once you visit this website, you can see the navigation and add to cart button
http://wh-clone.kbethos.com/

I implement that when I scroll down, navigation is stick on the top and add to cart button,actually it is not child element of navigation, might be appended to the navigation as last child.

When I scroll up, the navigation would be located on original position but add to cart button still keep its location.

How can I handle it? This is my code:

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
var height = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

if(height  > 150) {
    jQuery('.header-minicart').appendTo('#custommenu');
    jQuery('#header-nav').addClass('fixed-menu');
    jQuery('.header-minicart').addClass('fixed-minicart');

}else{
    /*WHAT SHOULD I DO IN HERE? */
    jQuery('#header-nav').removeClass('fixed-menu');
    jQuery('.header-minicart').removeClass('fixed-minicart');

}
});

</script>
<style>
.fixed-menu{ 
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 9999999999;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.fixed-minicart{ 
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

This is html code of add to cart btn and looks like

```
 <div class="header-minicart">              
        <a href="-" data-target-element="#header-cart" class="skip-link skip-cart  no-count">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="label">Cart</span>
        <span class="count">0</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="header-nav" class="skip-content">
    <div class="nav-container" id="wp-nav-container">  
    <div id="custommenu" class="" style=""><div class="menu">
    <div class="parentMenu menu0">
        <a href="-">
            <span>Home</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu666" class="menu" onmouseover="wpShowMenuPopup(this, event, 'popup666');" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, 'popup666', 'menu666')">
    <div class="parentMenu">
    <a class="level0" href="javascript:void(0);" rel="-">
    <span>BLANKS / CLASSICS</span>
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu677" class="menu" onmouseover="wpShowMenuPopup(this, event, 'popup677');" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, 'popup677', 'menu677')">
    <div class="parentMenu">
    <a class="level0" href="javascript:void(0);" rel="-">
    <span>SNAPBACK</span>
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I just want to put the add to cart btn before `.clearboth`

Comment: Can you show the HTML code?

Comment: @SpaceDogCS I add the html code! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this code

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
var height = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

if(height  > 150) {
    jQuery('.header-minicart').appendTo('#custommenu');
    jQuery('#header-nav').addClass('fixed-menu');
    jQuery('.header-minicart').addClass('fixed-minicart');

}else{
    jQuery('.account-cart-wrapper').append(jQuery('.header-minicart'));
    jQuery('#header-nav').removeClass('fixed-menu');
    jQuery('.header-minicart').removeClass('fixed-minicart');

}
});

</script>
```

Comment: I'm really thank you for your helping but i adapt your code to my website and after scroll up, navigation is totally removed!